how to express a polynomial $q(D)$ of degree $k$ as powers of $(D - a)$
I am doing a proof of Generalized Exponential Response Formula where it is used to find the particular solution $ x_p $ for the equation $ p(D)x = e^{at} $, where $ a $ is a real or complex constant and $ a $ is an $ s $ fold zero of the polynomial $ p(D) $, we follow these steps:
The particular solution $ x_p $ will be of the form:
$$ x_p = t^s e^{at}/p^{(s)}(a)$$
Now there is a step which I can't understand where they write a polynomial $q(D)$ of degree $k$ as powers of $(D - a)$ as follows:
$$ q(D) = q(a) + c_1 (D - a) + c_2 (D - a)^2 + \ldots + c_k (D - a)^k $$
How does one do this?

Explicitly, $c_j = q^{(j)}(a)/j!$ where $q^{(j)}$ denotes the $j$-th derivative of $q$. This is the Taylor series for $q$ at $a$.

It is completely unnecessary to talk about derivatives here. Just consider the polynomial $f(t) = q(t + a)$, which has some expansion into powers of $t$. Then substitute $t = D - a$.
